# How to click a JavaScript confirm popup via excel vba without embedded onclick

Tags: javascript, html, vba

HTML and function code is

```
function resetClick() {
    var tempChanged = "X";
    var tempTemplate = "";
    if (tempChanged == "X" && tempTemplate != "X") {
        if (confirm("Modification in progress , do you wish to save?"))
<!--      changed okcode from reset to /8 so that the exit command code will be used. -->
<!--            SetOkCode("netmzps_0000004_100", "/8");  -->
       SettingOkCode("/8", "netmzps_0000004_100","","","");
    }
    else
<!--      changed okcode from reset to /8 so that the exit command code will be used. -->
<!--            SetOkCode("neetmzps_0000004_100", "/8");  -->
       SettingOkCode("/8", "netmzps_0000004_100","","","");
}

<a href="javascript:resetClick();" class="TELUSHighlightButton" name="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Start over&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" title="Click here to initialise all fields." onmouseover="status=' ';return true;"  onmouseout="status=' ';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Start over&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

I found a similar problem that removed an onclick value, 
but this isn't a java embeddded function!

Seaching the web hasn't show any real solution!

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was to not creat the problem!

At first I tried to execute the script attached to the button!

```
myBrowser.Document.parentWindow.execScript "resetClick()"
```

But that called the confirm routine! Instead I executed what the resetclick did, then did a submit which bypassed the problem! Works like a charm!

```
myBrowser.Document.parentWindow.execScript "SetOkCode('netmzps_0000004_100', '/8')"
    Do While myBrowser.Busy Or myBrowser.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
 Loop

myBrowser.Document.parentWindow.submit
myBrowser.Quit
```

Pete